# Run both applications in solution while debugging client-server app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have solution that contain two projects - client and server. Currently I need to debug client side, but to debug it I need to run server one. Additionally it would be nice to have possibility to place breakpoints and go through them in server application side while debugging client side.

How to run server application when starting debug client side?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 8):

[Multiple startup projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413(v=vs.100).aspx) to the rescue - this setting is available from the solution context menu.

[image]